# alternative gyro for Turtlebot

Tags: ros, hardware, gyro, turtlebot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As the [Sparkfun ADXRS613 breakout](http://www.sparkfun.com/products/9059) gyro for the turtlebot is not available from sparkfun anymore, I was wondering if the [Active-Robots Gyro Breakout Board MLX90609-E2](http://www.active-robots.com/sensors/gyros/gyro-breakout-board-mlx90609-e2.html) is an interchangeable alternative?

It seems to have the same sensitivities, rate and required voltages.. Only thing different I see is that the standard capacitor sets it to ~36Hz instead of ~361Hz for the adxrs613. Switching out the capacitor should fix this, is it useful though?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11220/alternative-gyro-for-turtlebot/) by [Marco](https://answers.ros.org/users/920/marco/) on ROS Answers with karma: 77 on 2011-09-14

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is a duplicate question of this one:
http://answers.ros.org/question/2122/gyro-substitute-for-turtlebot

And more info:
http://answers.ros.org/question/1400/using-a-different-gyro-on-a-turtlebot

---

Originally posted by [AHornung](https://answers.ros.org/users/141/ahornung/) with karma: 5904 on 2011-09-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2